# Open cart 2.0, in WAMP the basic ui is not visibile to the other pc

Tags: wamp, opencart

Hi i just installed openCart in my localhost, and in my computer everythings fine,
and after Putting online my WAMPserver
i am able to see my page using other computer by ip address
but the design or the basic theme,css of my open cart is not loading...
any idea? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `config.php` files (both in the root and in /admin) and change all the URLs from (probably) `http://localhost/` to the IP e.g. `http://192.168.1.123/`

Note: you will need to use the IP when browsing from BOTH PCs in future.

That's probably the simplest solution. Depending on your WAMP setup, you can also set up an alias in the vhost e.g. "myopencart" and then add an entry in your hosts file on each PC to map this domain to the correct IP.

In the vhost:

`ServerAlias myopencart`

Hosts file on the hosting PC:

`127.0.0.1 myopencart`

and on the other PC:

`192.168.1.123 myopencart`

Then you can hit myopencart in the browser instead, which is nicer than an IP. But meh, that's all it is... nicer.

If you need more help with that, just google "virtualhost wamp", there are a million guides out there.

Comment: thanks @rjdown right now i can't vote it up i still need 15 reputation hahahaha but your answer correct,

Comment: @CodeCrisis great! If an answer is correct then it's good to "accept" it (click the tick under the arrows).

Comment: i visit my question to fill an answer bcus i figured it out and i have read your post hehehehe, its exactly what i did, THANKS @rjdown right now i can't vote it up i still need 15 reputation hahahaha but your answer correct, i thought my question is going to be ignored again, + respect for those who keep answering newbie question...   new learned ( Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes hehehehe)